# jQuery unbind event from whole array

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

Hi does anybody know how is jquery unbind function woking?I have a jquery powered photogallery where I am binding some stuff on load event(change image and so on)..But when the user is quickly walking through the gallery I want to unbind "older" events and than bind load event only on the last image. Otherwise the user will see every image he walked through for a tiny moment and I only want to show the last one..(performance, UX,..)I store every loaded(not exactly loaded, too every requested) image in an array, so everytime I call my loadImage function I call `jQuery(myArrayWithImages).unbind("load.backgroundImagesLoader")`
but it seems it does not work, the load events are still there (its a bit weird, I cant find it in debugger, but I see it:))
Is there any way to unbind the events from whole array, or from whole js instance, except do it through foreach?

Here is some code snippet..It is whole loadImage function..

```
function loadImage(index , showLoading, callback){
    if(backgroundImages==undefined) backgroundImages=Array();
    //if(backgroundImages[window.location.hash][index]==undefined)backgroundImages[window.location.hash][index] = Array();

            jQuery("#galleryEl .sig_thumb a").each( function( pos , el ) {
            var wh_bg_b = getVierwportSize();
            if(index == pos){
                    var bg_img_path_b = jQuery(el).attr('href');
                    var size = 'max';
                    if ( bg_img_path_b != undefined ) {
                    if ( (wh_bg_b[0] < 1281) && (wh_bg_b[1] < 801) ) {
                        size = 'min';
                        bg_img_path_b = bg_img_path_b.substring( 0, bg_img_path_b.lastIndexOf("/") ) + "/1280/" + bg_img_path_b.substring( bg_img_path_b.lastIndexOf("/")+1 );
                    } else if ( (wh_bg_b[0] < 1441) && (wh_bg_b[1] < 901) ) {
                        size = 'med';
                        bg_img_path_b = bg_img_path_b.substring( 0, bg_img_path_b.lastIndexOf("/") ) + "/1440/" + bg_img_path_b.substring( bg_img_path_b.lastIndexOf("/")+1 );
                    }
                }


                    console.log("test");
                    if(backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b]!=undefined){
                        if(backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b].loaded=="true"){
                        //console.log(index+" "+backgroundImages[window.location.hash][index][size]['loaded']);
                        if(typeof callback=='function'){
                            callback.call(this, bg_img_path_b);
                        }   }
                        else if(backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b].loaded=="loading"){
                            jQuery(backgroundImages).unbind('load.backgroundImages');

                            jQuery(backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b]).bind('load.backgroundImages',function(){
                                backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b].loaded="true";
                                if(typeof callback=='function'){
                                    callback.call(this, bg_img_path_b);
                                    //console.log("loaded "+index);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else{


                    backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b]=new Image();
                    backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b].src = bg_img_path_b;
                    backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b].loaded="loading";
                    jQuery(backgroundImages).unbind('load.backgroundImages');

                    jQuery(backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b]).bind('load.backgroundImages',function(){
                        backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b].loaded="true";
                        if(typeof callback=='function'){
                            callback.call(this, bg_img_path_b);
                            //console.log("loaded "+index);
                        }
                    });
                }
                console.log(backgroundImages[bg_img_path_b]);

                //console.log(size);
                //console.log(backgroundImages);


            }


    } );
```

}

Comment: If you can post your script up that will make helping easier.  Also this tool is useful for debugging events http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

Comment: So it is already fixed..I store the pointer to last image I binded on in variable and before nexr binding I unbind..I must split the events to two, to be able set the image as loaded(.loaded value). Everything is ok now..But when I see the code now, the each cycle on beginning is not the right way to do that quick:)I changed it by using eq(index) function:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind not like

```
jQuery(myArrayWithImages).unbind("load.backgroundImagesLoader")
```

but

```
jQuery(myArrayWithImages).unbind(load.backgroundImagesLoader).
```

Just read manual, you can use namespaces:

```
$('#foo').bind('click.myEvents', handler);
```

and

```
$('#foo').unbind('click.myEvents');
```

Comment: but I am using namespaces...
I think there is problem I am binding on single array elements and then unbinding from whole array..so I will try to keep a last selector I had binded on a and then I will be able to unbind from last inserted(accessed) index..it will be too more efficient...i hope it will bw working